# can't find unsigned APK in android studio, where is it?

Tags: android, android-studio

So I tried run, make, assemble, from android studio on a vanilla hello world app (it's the app that it creates from the default file -> new project and I can't find the unsigned APK in the MyApplication/build folder.  I can generate a signed apk going through the build menu but I can't seem to find the auto generated debug apk.

I also tried following some instructions on going through the project structure menu but I can't find a plus button that adds an artifact.

Comment: Usually at out/ directory. You can set a different path on the project settings though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your project has modules (e.g., an `app/`) module, APKs go in the module. So, I would look in `app/build/outputs/apk/` (again, assuming that you have an `app/` module).

Answer (score 0):

You should build apk by gradle.

1.Enter the root directory of your project and command **./gradlew -v** to download gradle.
![./gradlew -v][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMbGO.jpg if you download successfully, you'll see this formation.

2.command **./gradlew clean** to download dependencies of gradle.
![./gradlew clean][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlWQR.jpg if successfully, you'll see this formation.

3.command **./gradlew build** to build and generate apks.

Enter **[Your-project]/app/build/outputs/apk**, you will see app-debug.apk, app-debug-unaligned.apk, app-release-unsigned.apk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option  Build -> Analyse Apk and you can find the path of your apk